# RecyclerView Not Showing up

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have some text views and a button to be displayed on top of a RecyclerView. I seem to be doing everything right, but somehow nothing is being displayed. I also checked thru logs and the RecyclerView should have data!

This is not the very first time to display RecyclerViews. However, this is the first time I am displaying a RecyclerView with some elements on top of it.

1. activity_home.xml - this is the main home page

   ```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/home_RL"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/top_LL"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/first_name"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
           android:layout_weight="2"
           android:hint="FirstName" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/last_name"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
           android:layout_weight="2"
           android:hint="LastName" />

       <ProgressBar
           android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:visibility="gone" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/submit"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:onClick="goButton"
           android:text="GO" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/load"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
           android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:onClick="loadButton"
           android:text="L" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/nameList"
       android:layout_below="@+id/top_LL"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
   </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView></RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. name_list_item.xml

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/list_first_name"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           tools:text="first name"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/list_last_name"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           tools:text="second name"/>
   </LinearLayout>

   <View
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="1dp"
       android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
   ```
3. Name Adapter

   public class NameAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

   ```
       private List<Name> mNameList;
       private Context mContext;

       public NameAdapter(Context context) {
           mContext = context;
       }

       @Override
       public NameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
           LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.name_list_item, viewGroup, false);
           return new NameViewHolder(view);
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(final NameViewHolder nameViewHolder, int position) {

           String firstName = mNameList.get(position).getFirst();
           String lastName = mNameList.get(position).getLast();

           nameViewHolder.mListItemFirstName.setText(firstName);
           nameViewHolder.mListItemLastName.setText(lastName);
       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           if (mNameList == null) {
               return 0;
           }
           return mNameList.size();
       }


       class NameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

           TextView mListItemFirstName;
           TextView mListItemLastName;

           private NameViewHolder(View itemView) {
               super(itemView);

               mListItemFirstName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_first_name);
               mListItemLastName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_last_name);
           }

       }



       public void swapNameList(List<Name> nameList) {
           if (nameList != null) {
               nameList.clear();
           }
           mNameList = nameList;
           this.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   ```

   }

UPDATE: ISSUE RESOLVED
new code should be:

```
public void swapNameList(List<Name> nameList) {
                if (mNameList != null) {
                    mNameList.clear();
                }
                mNameList = nameList;
                this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here

```
   if (nameList != null) {
        nameList.clear();
    }
```

you are clearing the list you pass as parameter. This

```
public void swapNameList(List<Name> nameList) {
    mNameList = nameList;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

should fix it. (You don't need to clear anything since you are overriding the list every time you call `swapNameList`)

Comment: wow you are right!!!! gosh, I guess i was tired and didnt see it. my code should have been if(mNameList !=null) then clear the list first

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** The problem here is you are carrying the list forward and clearing it off before assigning to the adapter, hence:

Instead of:

```
nameList.clear();
```

Write:

```
mNameList.clear();
```

That's all.